# Array from SQL and extract not working PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I am brand new to PHP so thank you for your help.

I am trying to get the contents of a certain row in an SQL table and put it into an array, then put each of the values into its own variable.

I need them in both the array and in the variables for a few different reasons on the page.

The table has three columns: student_id, first_name, and last_name

I am using this code:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE student_id = '$studentid'",$connection);
$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $array[] = array($row['student_id'], $row['last_name'], $row['first_name']);
}
extract($array);
```

But when I try to echo $last_name on the page, I get an undefined variable error. Am I using extract wrong?

Any suggestions for accomplishing this?

I know, I am using the old SQL not the mysqli, but I cannot change to it yet for a few reasons, so thank you for helping me with the old code.

You're helping me learn to code!:) Thanks for helping me debug.

Comment: Brand new? And using a deprecated api? How can this be?  !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully there is only one student with this id so this should work :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE student_id = '$studentid'",$connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
extract($row);
```

Note that `mysql` is deprecated and that you should use `mysqli` instead.

https://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: I'm happy for you! now, if you like my answer, please validate (clicking the grey "v" left of the answer content) it, as it rewards me for my efforts ;)

Comment: @Loïc I think you meant grey "^", your suggestion is a downvote ("v") haha

Comment: Yeah, sorry! haha I had to wait the ten minutes but then forgot to check it.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through one result set and then taking the results out of an array and putting it into another array with no keys. Yes. That is incorrect. :)

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
extract($row);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$array[] = array($row['student_id'], $row['last_name'], $row['first_name']);`

what does means is that you will have a multi dimensional array with

`array = array[0]=(1,lastname1,firstname1),array[1]`

try to print out

`$array[0]` for the first student and you will notice the keys for that arrray are funky. now change that line from

`$array[] = array($row['student_id'], $row['last_name'], $row['first_name']);`

to

```
$array[] = array('id'=> $row['student_id'], 'last_name'=> $row['last_name'], 'first_name'=> $row['first_name']);
```

then you can do
`$array[0]['first_name']` to get the first name